# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '13' Error

Tags: php, mysql

So i was trying to get a login page that appears only to the members that are that level and them it says:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '13' (T_LNUMBER), expecting ')' in /home/limecd/public_html/admin/restrito.php on line 10

```
    <?
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    require_once("conecta.php");
    /////////////////////////////////////////
    echo "$level_usuario";
    $level = $level_usuario;
    //LEVELS THAT CAN ACCESS THE PAGE
    $lv = array(''13'',''100'',''10'',''25'',''14'');
    //SE NÃO TIVER VARIÁVEIS REGISTRADAS 
    //RETORNA PARA A TELA DE LOGIN 
    if( (!isset($_SESSION[id])) AND (!isset($_SESSION[name])) )
    { 
    Header("Location: index.html"); 
    };
    //level WITH GRANTED ACCESS
    if ($level_usuario == $lv[0] || $level_usuario == $lv[1] || $level_usuario == $lv[2] || $level_usuario == $lv[3] || $level_usuario == $lv[4] || $level_usuario == $lv[100] || $level_usuario == $lv[13])
    {
    echo "<center>";
    echo "Página secreta";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br><br><a href=''restrita2.php''>Restrita2</a>";
    echo "<br><br><a href=''restrita3.php''>Restrita3</a>";  
    echo "<br><br><a href=''logout.php''>Logout</a>";
    echo "</center>";
     }
    else
    {
    //DESTROY THE VARIABLES
    unset($_SESSION[id]); 
    unset($_SESSION[usuario]); 
    unset($_SESSION[nome]); 
    unset($_SESSION[level_usuario]);
    session_destroy(); 
    //REDIRECT FOR THE HOMEPAGE
    Header("Location: index.html"); 
  }
  ;
  ?>
```

This code would load a page called restrito.php and them it would show a menu that is restrict for the users!

Comment: Two single quotes `''` is not the same thing as a double quote `"`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$lv = array(''13'',''100'',''10'',''25'',''14'');
```

change to this

```
 $lv = array('13','100','10','25','14');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using two single quotes. Either use single quotes like the following:

```
$lv = array('13','100','10','25','14');
```

or, double quotes like the following:

```
$lv = array("13","100","10","25","14");
```

or, since they are integers remove the quotes all together (unless you are trying to type cast) like:

```
$lv = array(13,100,10,25,14);
```